# Как получить элемент по функции onclick(). python selenium

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, парсер, selenium

```html
<span onclick="funcjs['start_youtube'](70581, '7afde6cb0ce7df9014b2e73e293a524a', 'likes-start', 'likes');" title="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mBfhPKGzF0w" style="cursor:pointer;color:#006699;">Лайкосик Под Видосик</span>
```

Подобных элементов,но с разным тексом внутри много, мне их нужно получить, чтобы потом на них кликнуть.

Comment: Можно css-селектором `span[onclick]` через метод `find_elements_by_css_selector` найти такие элементы. Если нужно еще и содержимое учитывать, то `span[onclick^=funcjs]`

Comment: Спасибо. Можно ещё спросить? Как найти элемент по css стилям. Например по цвету color:#006699;.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно `css-селектором` `span[onclick]` через метод `find_elements_by_css_selector` найти такие элементы. Если нужно еще и содержимое учитывать, то `span[onclick^=funcjs]`:

```
for el in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('span[onclick^=funcjs]'):
    print(el)
```

- ℹ️ `^=` ищет по началу значения, т.е. `onclick^=funcjs` - поиск тегов, у которых есть атрибут `onclick`, чье значение начинается с `funcjs`
- ℹ️ `*=` ищет по нахождению значения в атрибуте, т.е. `style*="color:#006699"` - поиск тегов с атрибутом `style`, у которого в значении есть строка `color:#006699`

Если нужно ориентироваться на стиль, то ищем по атрибуту `style`, покажу сразу пример с двумя условиями:

```css
span[onclick^=funcjs][style*="color:#006699"]
```